# Pandas - most efficient way to iterate over rows

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a (for me) rather complex analysis ahead. In a table I have to find the minimum of out of four columns. The column with the smallest value is saved as my reference number. For this I use idxmin function and it works perfectly well.

However, then I need to check on a condition in the same row (Length of a string) and if the length is below a certain threshold I will have to change my reference number to a different value (next higher value in the table, e.g. the column one left).

Example:

| C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | Condition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 10 | 1 |  | 13 |
| 5000 | 200 | 20 | 1 | 15 |
| 300 | 50 | 5 |  | 13 |

In the first line the smallest value is C3 "1" and as the condition is 13, I have to change it to the value in C2 "10". In the second line the value is in C4 "1" and I can keep it because the condition is correct. Third line same as in the first line.

I was at first trying apply method but I am struggeling with moving from one row to another to get the actual value of the field as everything is applied on the entire dataframe. Else I can think of is basically using for-loop or iterrows. Performance is not so much of a factor. I actually dont care if the script runs for 1 minute or 5 minutes.

Thank you for all your ideas & suggestions.

Comment: 10 is still < 13, shouldn't the first row rather match C1?

Comment: Is the value chosen supposed to be greater than the condition? The meaning is not clear to me.

Comment: The meaning 13 and 15 is based on the length of a material number. If the material number is 13 digits long it must be treated differerntly than a 15 digit material number. So basically the differentiation is between 13 and 15 digits of length. Hope this makes it more understanable :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the column index of the **minimum value above threshold**, you can first mask your data to only keep the values above Condition:

```
cols = df.filter(regex='C\d+').columns
# ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4']

df['idxmin'] = df[cols].mask(df[cols].lt(df['Condition'], axis=0)).idxmin(axis=1)
```

alternative syntax:

```
df['idxmin'] = df[cols].where(df[cols].ge(df['Condition'], axis=0)).idxmin(axis=1)
```

output:

```
     C1   C2  C3   C4  Condition idxmin
0   100   10   1  NaN         13     C1
1  5000  200  20  1.0         15     C3
2   300   50   5  NaN         13     C2
```

intermediate:

```
df[cols].mask(df[cols].lt(df['Condition'], axis=0))
     C1     C2    C3  C4
0   100    NaN   NaN NaN
1  5000  200.0  20.0 NaN
2   300   50.0   NaN NaN
```

##### Alternative interpretation

If you want the second idxmin if the initial one is below threshold, **even if this second idxmin is below threshold**, this is a bit tricker. You should only mask the first value below threshold:

```
cols = df.filter(regex='C\d+').columns
# ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4']

m = df[cols].min(1)
df['idxmin2'] = df[cols].mask(df[cols].le(m.where(m.lt(df['Condition'])), axis=0)).idxmin(1)
```

output:

```
     C1   C2  C3   C4  Condition idxmin2
0   100   10   1  NaN         13      C2
1  5000  200  20  1.0         15      C3
2   300   50   5  NaN         13      C2
```